# how not to call a method when an exception occurs in celery?

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery code sample like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from proj.celery import app


@app.task
def add(x, y):
    try:
       return x + y
    except Exception,e:
       raise

@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    try:
       return x * y
    except Exception,e:
       raise


@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

So, I do not want to call the third task `xsum` if any of the first two tasks `add` and `mul` raise any exception. How do i do this in celery??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that in your case we are missing how you call the third task, anyway when we have one task depending from one or more other tasks we normally use a wrapper tasks that calls the first 2 tasks and wait for results, if both are successful than it calls the third tasks.
You can achieve this using awesome celery canvas

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html

Canvas let you implement common workflows like yours.
Probably in your case you can use the [Chord](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chords) canvas.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You will need to `revoke` the task:

```
from celery.task.control import revoke

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    try:
        return x + y
    except Exception,e:
        revoke(xsum.request.id)

@app.task
def mul(x, y):
    try:
        return x * y
    except Exception,e:
        revoke(xsum.request.id)


@app.task
def xsum(numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

Comment: I think you understand the other way round (or I did). The OP wants not to call the `xsum` if there is an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Llopis! I think I missed the _not_. I will think about this and update my answer accordingly.